# Animation horizontal line in Android

Tags: android, xml, drawable

How do I get the animation (moving horizontal line) centered on the center of the screen? In order to well illustrate this "effect" is used in respirators, life support (I mean my so-called "life line"). I care about the fact that this effect was available in the API 9> =

This is what I managed to cobble together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke
    android:dashGap="10px"
    android:dashWidth="30px"
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="#ff000000" />
 </shape>
```

Unfortunately, this is just a vertical line, and that just started playing with XML resources in Android, I have no idea how to get out of this situation

Comment: what means of this xml code?! code not related to your question please provide ture code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i understand you may need this article [Layout Change Animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html). simply can use it on your app and animate on Activity layout with 
 `<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    ...
/>`

hope to be usefull :)